# HTML Visibility Style

Tags: html

Can someone please help me solve this problem. I want to show a submit button when users click on the anchor tag. The problem is, the button is initially hidden, but when I click on the anchor tag, nothing happens
The HTML code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
    #reveal
    {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
     <a href="javascript:" onclick='showButton();'>k...@ccs.neu.edu</a>
 </div>
 <form>
     <input type="submit" value="show email address" id="reveal"/>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function showButton() {
        document.getElementById("reveal").style.visibility = visible;
    }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you look at the browsers console, you will see `Uncaught ReferenceError: visible is not defined`. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) ([even more docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)).

Comment: which is another way of saying it should be a string and not a variable that's not defined

Comment: @FelixKling I was going through Learn how to debug JavaScript link, and it said that the error will automatically be shown on the console. I am using Firefox, and it didn't show any error. Can you suggest me how I can see the errors?

Thanks

Comment: You have to open the web console: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console. And make sure the "JS" buttons is selected (which it is by default I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'visible'` instead of `visible`. You want to use a value, not a variable there.

Answer (score 2):

Use 
 `document.getElementById("reveal").style.visibility = 'visible';` 
 instead of 
`document.getElementById("reveal").style.visibility = visible;`

You do not want to assign a variable, but a value, which should be put on quotes.